# Javascript/jQuery Click after Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to insert a timer and a click to the next page of my form after the timer counts down. [Here's my form](http://casperfect.ca/test-1).

I believe I could implement something using either basic JS, or with jQuery (there's [this jQuery plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) that looks promising.

For the prompt pages, I need a 30 second countdown, and for the form page immediately after I need a 5 minute countdown. How to implement JS and/or jQuery into Wordpress and/or Gravity Forms specifically?

I don't really have much code to start from, but this is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    seconds = parseInt($("#countdown").attr('data-timelimit'));
    var date = new Date();
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + seconds);
    $('#countdown').countdown({
        date: date,
        onEnd: goToNextPage,
        render: function(date) {
            return $(this.el).html(""+ (this.leadingZeros(date.min)) + " : " + (this.leadingZeros(date.sec)) + " sec");
        }
    });

    $('#next_button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        goToNextPage();
    });
```

I didn't make this code myself, so I'm not sure if it works, or if this is the right track either.

Comment: Hi, please post a simple and concise code snippet here - not a link to your page. That not only helps us answer the question, but it also helps future searchers. Thanks!

Comment: OK! Sure thing, I'll try to make a relevant edit. @AnilRedshift

Answer (score 1):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) should work for your usecase. Something like this will navigate to google.com in 30 seconds:

If the timeout amount is variable, you can use javascript to query the data attribute and replace `30000` with that variable.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Could this code be altered to simply click "next" on my page? How would that be changed?

Comment: Should this work?

<code>

    setTimeout(
 jQuery("[value='Next']").click();
    }, 500);

</code>

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to programmatically click on your `$('#next_button')` button once the timer is up, try this. I haven't used `countdown()` but I suppose `onEnd` accepts an anonymous function

```
    seconds = parseInt($("#countdown").attr('data-timelimit'));
    var date = new Date();
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + seconds);
    $('#countdown').countdown({
        date: date,
        onEnd: function (){
            $('#next_button').click();
        },
        render: function(date) {
            return $(this.el).html(""+ (this.leadingZeros(date.min)) + " : " + (this.leadingZeros(date.sec)) + " sec");
        }
    });

    $('#next_button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        goToNextPage();
    });
```